# Vue & Nuxt - loading page or animation between pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm making a website with many pages using Vue & Nuxt.
I have three pages to working with.

- **page A** : page with menu, by click, redirect to page B
- **page B** : page with other purpose. contains asynchronous function (`asyncData`, `axios`) and can move to some subpages (**B-1**, **B-2**)
- **page C** : Loading page with animation (It could not be page, could be just animation)

[image: vue page description]

---

What I want to do is when moving from **page A** to **page B**, I want to show **page C (or loading animation)** so users can feel like they're moving to a new service.
And also, want to show **page C (or loading animation)** until async function in **page B** finishes.
I could make it by wrapping whole template with `isLoading`, so when `asyncData` running, it shows animation.

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoading">
    // Loading animation
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    // page B
  </div>
</template>

// ~~~

data() {
  return {
    isLoading: true
  }
}

asyncData() {
  // some async functions
  isLoading: false
}
```

But, problem here is when moving in **page B** (**B** -> **B-1** -> **B**), it calls `asyncData` everytime, shows loading animation again.
I want to show loading animation when only moving from **page A** to **page B**

What i've tried

- `beforeRouteEnter` : tried, but seems not what i wanted
- `mounted` & `updated` : same as `asyncData`, calls everytime

Thanks for read and any help or documentation would be help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got your question very well you will need to make a component/page C.vue, and
in page B.vue in script do this

```
<script>

import Loading from '@/components/C.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
 components: { Loading },
  data(){
        return {
            isLoading: true, //make is loading true
            token: localStorage.getItem('user_data'),
            errors: {},
            myData: {}
        }
    },
    methods:{
        yourFunction(){
            axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/my_url').then(response => {
                this.myData= response.data
            }).catch(errors => {
                this.errors = errors.response.data.errors
            }).finally(() => { //add finally in your axios and add setTimeout function
                setTimeout(function () {
                    this.isLoading =  false
                }.bind(this), 500);
            })
        },
    },
    created(){
        document.title = `Course Lessons - Training`
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${this.token}` 
        this.yourFunction() 
    }
}
</script>
```

in your B.vue template do this

```
<template>
    <div !isLoading">
        //your stuffs
        </div>
    <div v-else>
      <Loading /> loading page/component
    </div>
</template>
```

In C.vue you can put your animation and it will appear when loading

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's great idea but some of my code in template got error while trying this :(. But, it's really good idea TY!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify custom loading component in Nuxt.js

Create a loading component `~/components/loading.vue`

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loading" class="loading-page">
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      loading: false
    }),
    methods: {
      start() {
        this.loading = true
      },
      finish() {
        this.loading = false
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .loading-page {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
```

Update `nuxt.config.json` to use custom loading component

```
export default {

  //.....
  //other configuration


  loading: '~/components/LoadingBar.vue'
}
```

For more about `loading`: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading

Comment: TY, but doesn't it works for every page? I want to show only one loading page between page A and page B. But, thank you for answer!

Comment: you cannot show it between pages, but you can place it as component in a page, when someone access the page it will load first. If you place between you will have to use redirect. It is very fast that you may not see the effect

Comment: @HJKim you may need to get data from api/axios without blocking the page load and hide loading component by setting `loading = false` after the request is completed(get data from beforeMount/mounted).Think this is the best and easy approach IMO.

Answer (score 0):

easy; make a custom loading component then import that in your layouts.
handle showing that component with a v-if and a store variable
first make a loading component

```
<template>
<div class="loading-backdrop">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="b b1"></div>
        <div class="b b2"></div>
        <div class="b b3"></div>
        <div class="b b4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'Loadingpage'
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.loading-backdrop {
    background-color: rgba(63, 60, 60, 0.158);
  backdrop-filter: blur(14px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 100000;

}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
//   position: absolute;
//   top: 50%;
//   left: 50%;
//   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box .b {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: ro 2s infinite;
}

.box .b1 {
  border-color: #4A69BD;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.box .b2 {
  border-color: #F6B93B;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.box .b3 {
  border-color: #2ECC71;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.box .b4 {
  border-color: #34495E;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes ro {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-180deg);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
}
</style>
```

in app.vue (or in nuxt in the main layout) import the Loading component and mount and unmount it with a state

```
<Loading v-if="state.loading" />
```

then handle loading state in your axiosconfig.js file using request and response interceptor

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        that.state.loading = true
        return config
        }
    }
)
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (res)=> {
         that.state.loading = true
     },
     (err)=> {
         that.state.loading = true
     }, 
)
```

Comment: Please give an example of the code.